# The input value I enter does not show up in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, dom

I am writing a text based game for a college competition and am very new to JS & HTML DOM. I have successfully created an input, and am trying to test it. However, when I type into the input and press enter nothing is logged onto the console...

```
function new_input(){
    let input = document.createElement("INPUT");
    input.setAttribute("type", "text");
    input.setAttribute("id", "input");
    document.body.appendChild(input);
    let x = $("input").val();
    console.log(x);
```

Comment: You need an onChange event to see how the input value changes as you type or an onClick event for a “submit” button on the input to see your final input after clicking the button.

Comment: You need a method to detect when something is typed into the input. Perhaps an `onChange` attribute on the input element? something like this: `<input onChange="new-input()">`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Input not triggering change event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57628948/input-not-triggering-change-event)

Comment: Change last 2 lines to `$("#input").change(function(){ console.log($(this).val()) })`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do need to handle the click with the help of a callback.

When wanting to do so use the following code instead of the last two lines

```
input.onkeypress = (e) => {
    if(e.keyCode === 13) {
        console.log(input.value);
    }
}
```